# Why does toString on an IntArray adds an address to a list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have just started playing with Kotlin, and was going through the Udacity bootcamp course for Kotlin.

I want to solve below problem statement:

1. Create an integer array of numbers called numbers, from 11 to 15.
2. Create an empty mutable list for Strings.
3. Write a for loop that loops over the array and adds the string representation of each number to the list.
4. Additionally see the nos are added properly (print out the contents of the list).

Code:

```
var numbers : IntArray = intArrayOf(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
var strList : MutableList<String> = mutableListOf<String>()

println("Now adding nos to strList")
for (number in numbers) {
    strList.add(numbers.toString())
}

println(strList)
```

The weird part is I see a result like below:

```
Now adding nos to strList
[[I@3bc04539, [I@3bc04539, [I@3bc04539, [I@3bc04539, [I@3bc04539]
```

I know this sounds dead simple, but why does Kotlin print a reference to the no and not the actual number itself?

Comment: Because that IS the result of the toString.. (the “includes a reference” is a Java thing, see Object#toString). In general, toString in collections does NOT result in a useful introspection of their contents. This is arguably “good”: what should be the toString of a collection with a million elements?

Comment: Thank you for the input. The problem was created by a silly typo. However what you mention makes sense. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the real problem here is that your line:

```
strList.add(numbers.toString())
```

shoud probably be:

```
strList.add(number.toString())
```

As is, it's trying to print the whole array each time.  And since IntArray doesn't seem to implement `toString()` itself, you get the default one in `Object`, which is unique but not very helpful.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Boy do i feel a little dumb currently. A silly typo. Thank you gidds for catching this.

Comment: We all make slip-ups like that from time to time — and they're often embarrassingly easy for someone else to spot :-)  (If it's any consolation, two earlier answers had also missed it!)

Answer (score 0):

Try contentToString instead of toString:

```
strList.add(numbers.contentToString())
```

Which results in:

```
[[11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to gidds.

The error was a silly typo wherein instead of `number` corrected by @gidds , i was adding `numbers` every time. Adding a list to a collection results in a mem address as per Java logic and not in introspection of the contents as was pointed out user2864740. Thank you people for the help.

This is resolved.